# How do I use VBA to flatten a table in Excel where data is split between rows?

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, datatables

I currently have a raw data table in Excel that summarizes the status of Phases A, B, and C for a given Engagement. Some Engagements may not have data for all 3 phases.

```
Row| EngagementID | A_date | A_status | B_date | B_status | C_date | C_status
1  |      201     |   2/2  | Approved |        |          |        |          
2  |      201     |        |          |  3/5   | Approved |        |          
3  |      201     |        |          |        |          |  4/1   |  Pending  
4  |      203     |   2/12 | Submitted|        |          |        |          
5  |      203     |        |          |  2/20  | Approved |        |          
6  |      207     |   2/5  | Approved |        |          |        |
```

I am trying to flatten the table to look like this:

```
Row| EngagementID | A_date | A_status | B_date | B_status | C_date | C_status
1  |      201     |   2/2  | Approved |  3/5   | Approved |  4/1   |  Pending 
2  |      203     |   2/12 | Submitted|  2/20  | Approved |        |         
3  |      207     |   2/5  | Approved |        |          |        |
```

---

### The Issue: Multiple Instances

There are, however, circumstances where the same EngagementID has multiple instances. For example, it may have the following:

```
    Row| EngagementID | A_date | A_status | B_date | B_status | C_date | C_status
    1  |      201     |   2/2  | Approved |        |          |        |          
    2  |      201     |        |          |  3/5   | Approved |        |          
    3  |      201     |        |          |  3/18  | Pending  |        |           
    4  |      201     |        |          |        |          |  5/20  |  Pending  
    5  |      201     |        |          |        |          |  5/15  |  Submitted
```

I am trying to make the VBA flexible enough so that, in these cases, the table would be transformed to

```
Row| EngagementID | A_date | A_status | B_date | B_status | C_date | C_status
1  |      201     |   2/2  | Approved |  3/5   | Approved |  5/20  |  Pending 
2  |      201     |   2/2  | Approved |  3/18  | Pending  |  5/15  |  Submitted
```

I am able to solve the single instance aspect with the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub test()
Dim R As Long
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
R = 2
Count = 0
Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & R))
    If Cells(R, 1).Value = Cells(R + 1, 1).Value Then
        Count = Count + 1
    Else
        i = 1
        Do While i <= Count
            Cells(R - Count, 2 + (2 * i)).Value = Cells(R - Count + i, 2 + (2 * i))
            Cells(R - Count, 3 + (2 * i)).Value = Cells(R - Count + i, 3 + (2 * i))
            i = i + 1
        Loop
            i = 1
            Do While i <= Count
                Rows(R - Count + i).Delete
                i = i + 1
                R = R - 1
            Loop
        Count = 0
    End If
R = R + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

However, this does not account for the multiple instances.
Any ideas as to where I might be able to adjust the VBA to accommodate for this "multiple-instance" scenario would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Basically you want to flatten everything according to matching engagement ID, but the result could still be "ragged" edged if there isn't a nice neat compression by ID? So there is no real relation for reading across a row except that it is information for the ID for that column header? i.e. each row does not constitute a record.

Comment: Are IDs always sequential or can they be spaced out?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by IDs being spaced out? As far as your initial questions, I think you have it right- one row does not constitute a record (unless that row only has information for one phase). Instead, one row is created for each instance of a phase, and one record would be formed by taking the information from each phase for a given ID (two records would be formed for the same ID if there were two instances from one or more of the phases). hope this helps answer your questions

Comment: i meant is it always 201, 201,202... or  can it be 201,202,203,204,201,201...

Comment: Oh ok. No, they will all be chunked together- the system I am using to export this data has the option to sort Engagement ID asc/desc

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Power Query** to handle this easily. It is an add-inn you can get for free and activate in Excel 2010+ (by default in Excel 2016 known as Get & Transform). There you can connect directly your source and edit your data as you want. For your particular case follow this steps:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim i As Long               ' loop
Dim iRow As Long            ' actual row to process
Dim i1stEmpy As Long        ' 1st empty cell
Dim iBlkStart As Long       ' this block starts here

Const colEngID = 2
Const colAdate = colEngID + 1
Const colAstat = colAdate + 1
Const colBdate = colAstat + 1
Const colBstat = colBdate + 1
Const colCdate = colBstat + 1
Const colCstat = colCdate + 1

iRow = 2        ' skip header row
Do While Trim$(Cells(iRow, 1)) <> vbNullString
    iBlkStart = iRow        ' 1st row of block of the same engagement
    For i = 0 To 2
        iRow = iBlkStart
        i1stEmpy = 0           ' next data comes here
        Do While Cells(iRow, colEngID) = Cells(iBlkStart, colEngID)
            If Trim$(Cells(iRow, colAdate + 2 * i)) = vbNullString Then
               If i1stEmpy = 0 Then i1stEmpy = iRow        ' set 1st empty cell
            Else
                If iRow <> iBlkStart And iRow <> i1stEmpy And i1stEmpy > 0 Then ' some data found
                    Cells(i1stEmpy, colAdate + 2 * i) = Cells(iRow, colAdate + 2 * i)  ' copy cell from below
                    Cells(i1stEmpy, colAstat + 2 * i) = Cells(iRow, colAstat + 2 * i)  ' copy cell from below
                    Cells(iRow, colAdate + 2 * i).Clear  ' clear cell
                    Cells(iRow, colAstat + 2 * i).Clear  ' clear cell
                    i1stEmpy = i1stEmpy + 1         ' set to next empty
                End If
            End If
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop
    Next i
    ' delete empty rows
    iRow = iBlkStart
    Do While Cells(iRow, colEngID) = Cells(iBlkStart, colEngID)
        If Trim$(Cells(iRow, colAdate)) = vbNullString And Trim$(Cells(iRow, colBdate)) = vbNullString And Trim$(Cells(iRow, colCdate)) = vbNullString Then    ' all cells are empty
            Cells(iRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Loop
Loop ' irow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this did not work- using the example in my original post (3rd table), the code you've posted shifts the B columns up correctly so that the first record with a B value is on the same row as the first record with an A value (and the second record with a B value is on the 2nd row), but the C columns only shift up 1 relative to the B columns, so that the 5/20-Pending record is on the 2nd row and the 5/15-Submitted record is on the 3rd row (the first occurrence of a value for any of the columns should be on the first row). Again, thanks anyways.