# Consolidating non-numerical data AND empty data in excel with key columns

Tags: excel, merge, office365, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with about 10 columns of data (numerical, non-numerical, dates, etc.) with a key identifier column on the very left (being the name of the person). I need to get the data from multiple rows, on to a singular row (still split up in the appropriate columns, but im having difficulty.  Here's a photo of a sample of my data:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet Screenshot]

I have 3 key rows, a student email, the date they attended, and the SKU associated with the class. If these three rows are the same, then i need all the rest of the data consolidated on one line. Here's what im looking for if i took the data above and processed it properly:

Cleaned Data Example

[image]

Consolidation tool doesnt work because it strips non-numerical data. I'm not looking to "merge" rows together either.  There are case examples in this excel where there will be 2 entries (same email address name) but they attended 2 different dates, so it's why the email and date are crucial to be lookup items when merging.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A pivot table looks like it would work, you can use the classic option to put the name/date/SKU fields in rows and sub the numeric portions in detail.

Comment: Yesterday I answered a similar question. You can use **Power Query** to handle this easily. Let me know if it worked for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018165/how-do-i-use-vba-to-flatten-a-table-in-excel-where-data-is-split-between-rows/49018482#49018482